# Empty folders when import existing Android project into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm trying to import an Android project into Eclipse by using File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace.

After project imported I found that src and res folder are empty !!! I don't know why I have this problem, any idea to solve this ??

Thanks,

Comment: What is the file structure of the project you're importing? Does it have src and res folders?

Comment: Yes, it's a android project structure and have files in both src, res folders. I check out project from svn server

Answer (score 1):

Really annoying indeed. I had the same problem with destroyed files when importing an existing project into Eclipse (Java ADT Package 22.0.5), when I previously had copied the project files into the workspace.

Solution: I copied the original (not the destroyed) project files to another directory and then imported them as "Existing projects into workspace" without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

MichaelSwede post was True, you Should Not Copy Paste The [Android Project] into WorkSpace Directly

1>The "WorkSpace" should contains only [.metadata]

2>Then Open Eclipse, Locate that "WorkSpace"

3>Then Import>Existing Android Project From Another Location except "WorkSpace"

Answer (score 0):

Use File -> Import -> Existing Project into Workspace instead.