# when import project in GitHub src is empty

Tags: android, eclipse

I found a project to [WaveView](https://github.com/john990/WaveView/tree/master/app)

after imported to the eclipse, I noticed that the src folder is empty and there is a folder called java.
I have read the following questions:

[qustion1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599358/empty-folders-when-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse)
[qustion2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650803/java-folder-in-android-project-and-the-src-is-empty)
But my problem is not resolved.
How do I use the above project?

Comment: Because the project your are trying to import in Eclipse is not a Eclipse compatible project.

The Project is developed in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks,Not a way to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you have not installed eclipse plugin for gradle. Follow [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html) to learn how to install and use eclipse plugin. Otherwise, you could simply install Android Studio and click on "Open an existing Android Studio project" to import the Application.